# Cannot move Screenlets in GNOME Shell

Tags: 11.10, gnome, screenlets

I have searched around and can't seem to find an answer. I have installed the 0.1.4 version of Screenlets on Ubuntu 11.10 running GNOME Shell, and everything functions okay except that I cannot move them. I can't seem to find any documentation about this problem; any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Was this problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in screenlets revision 740 (see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~screenlets-dev/screenlets/trunk/revision/740). If you install Screenlets from Dev PPA, you can move Screenlets by dragging them.

To enable Development versions PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a fix for this either but I did notice that you can adjust the X,Y position in the screenlets properties. It's not nearly as quick/easy, but it works.

If you restart GNOME Shell (Alt+F2, then enter "r" and hit ENTER) then you can move the screenlet as long as it's window property is not set to "Lock". For some reason, this only works if done right after restarting GNOME Shell, and once you click on anything else, the widgets all are locked in place again.

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04, installing from the ppa above did not help. It installs version 0.1.7, which sounds different from 740.

Selecting or deselecting the Window>Widget option does not work either.

Using the X/Y position scrolling in the widget properties is the only option that allowed me to move either the clock or countdown widgets.