# Where are Screenlets configuration files?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, screenlets

I have just installed Screenlets and the extra widget package thru software center.

Now I have gotten a little problem with a widget and therefore I want to reset the screenlet widget.

However I can not find the configuration files. I have looked in /home/~/.screenlets, but the folder is empty.

Does anyone knows where the config/properties for the widgets are stored?

Comment: See also: *Cannot move Screenlets in GNOME Shell* http://askubuntu.com/questions/81184/cannot-move-screenlets-in-gnome-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration for individual screenlets is stored in `~/.config/screenlets/` per the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). The actual screenlets are (non-compliantly) stored in `~/screenlets/`.

Refer to the [official FAQ](http://screenlets.org/index.php/FAQ#What.27s_in_.7E.2F.config.2Fscreenlets) for more details.

Comment: **UPDATE:** (tested for ***Ubuntu 11.10 + Unity***) If you are running **Screenlets v0.1.5** (latest), there should configuration files in: '**~/.config/screenlets/**'.  The old directory may still exist, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I found the files in /.config/screenlets. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for: `$HOME/.screenlets`.

Did you look (under the **command line**) for `~/.screenlets`

OR

did you use **Nautilus**, enable "Show Hidden Files", and look for folder: `.screenlets` ?

Comment: I have used nautilus and enabled "show hidden files", but .screenlet is completely empty and I know for sure that some of my screenlets has costum settings. If I am correct this should generate a config file in my home folder.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.10